# MIDI Keyboard has no sound

Tags: sound, midi

I have an Akai MPK Mini MIDI keyboard and haven't got something quite right as I am not getting sound. You can see in the screenshot that when I press keys on the Akai it recognizes that (the blue keys). (Note that the screenshot was take with JACK Audio off)

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the output port of the MPK (and the output port of VMPK, if you want to use it) to the input port of some synthesizer. At the moment, there is no synthesizer.

Two common software synthesizers are Timidity++ and FluidSynth, but if you have JACK, you probably want to use some [Jack synthesizer](https://jackaudio.org/applications/#sound-generators).